# Accounting Question: Computing margin of Safety Ratio

Tags: analysis, education, finance

Smith Company produces desk lamps. The information for June indicated that the selling price was $\$25$ per unit, variable costs were  $\$15$ per unit, fixed costs totaled $\$6,000$, and the margin of safety in dollars  was $\$12,500$. Smith currently sells 1,100 lamps and earns $\$5,000$ of profit. How much is Smith’s margin of safety ratio?

A.) 45.5%

B.) 2.5%

C.) 2.2%

D.) 40.0%

1. ***To compute Margin of Safety Ratio you take (Margin of Safety in
   Dollars/Actual (expected) Sales)***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  If they expect to sell 1,100 at $25 each, what are the expected sales?  You already have the margin of safety, so it is just division from there.

Comment: I was thinking that but I was not sure if I needed to calculate in the variable cost in the expected sales. Thanks!

Comment: Looks to me like there is a lot of extra information.  Maybe it is camouflage.